# CodeLite - build settings malfunction

Tags: c++, build, ide, codelite

from unknown reason I can't compile a single file/project in C++ in my CodeLite environment.

I'm using latest version of CodeLite, i.e.: 7.0 with pre-installed MinGW libraries. OS/ Windows 7.

Strangely after reinstallation, time and again I get the following error while trying to build/compile C++ project:

**C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C " -j 2 -e -f Makefile"**

**Name'-j' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file**

When I try to run the program (I was used to click run and get immediate results since it was compiling and running the code at one time) I get absolutely nothing.

Any idea how can I fix this strange issue ? Reinstalling IDE doesn't really help :(

Answer (score 1):

> C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C " -j 2 -e -f Makefile".

Do you have MinGW installed? CodeLite 7.0 **does not come with MinGW**

To fix your problem:

- Install MinGW, I recommend using [TDM-GCC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/files/TDM-GCC%20Installer/tdm-gcc-4.9.2.exe/download) (make sure you accept the default options by TDM-GCC installer, especially, the install location path)
- After the installation is completed, let CodeLite detect your compiler: `Settings->Build Settings->Compilers->Add Compiles->Add an existing compiler` and point CodeLite to the folder where you installed MinGW

  - You should now have this compiler configured in CodeLite. right Click  on your project and open the settings dialog (keyboard shortcut `Alt-F7`) : `Project settings->Common Settings->General->Compiler` and select your compiler from the list

Build your project again, this time it should work properly.

Also, I recommend you to use the latest weekly build (it contains a new "setup wizard" that includes installing a compiler), you can get it from [codelite's downloads page](http://codelite.org/support.php)

Eran

Comment: Is it possible to re-run the "setup wizard" at later point of time?

Comment: In CodeLite 7.1 (not yet released) it is possible to re-run the wizard from the Help menu